# typescript number of files and compile time

Tags: typescript

Working to see if our team can improve the TypeScript compile time of our project.  Using `--diagnostics` I can see that it currently takes about 2 min and has 1976 number of files.  Using the `--listFiles` I can see that about 500 of those are from various packages we use (e.g. material-ui).  That leaves 1476 files that are ours.  The team comes from a strong and extensive C# background and as such has a rule to place everything into its own files.  Even a tiny interface used by only one component or service. (And doesn't like to inline the typing).

I am wondering if that may be leading to the time it takes to compile.  If it wold be beneficial to look at combining/collapsing files.

In case it helps - this is a React app.  But my timings are taken with a pure `tcs` call.